# Blur effect on LockScreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, theos, cydia-substrate

I'm developing a CydiaSubstrate tweak and I would like to know how to disable the blur effect that appears on the lockscreen when we type the passcode. Does anyone have an idea ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: That is not going to be possible on a non-jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: I know it. I have a jailbroken iPhone and I want to develop a tweak that needs this NoBlur effect

Comment: @JānisK He prefaced it with "I'm developing a CydiaSubstrate tweak", I think he is aware of that. Edit: And I should've refreshed the page, Dayrona already said the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this thanks to a subredditer of /r/jailbreakdevelopers.
So the code to do that is the following :

```
%hook SBLockOverlayStyleProperties

-(float)blurRadius {
    return 0;
}

%end
```

Any way, thanks for those who have tried to help me !

Have a nice day :)